# Installing Minecraft mods without a bin folder or minecraft.jar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have been playing Minecraft for a while, but I recently decided to try mods.

I managed to bypass the bin folder, since everything I needed could apparently be found in the versions folder.

I am being told that I need a ***minecarft.jar*** folder, which isn't in 'versions', and I have no bin folder either.

I enabled "show hidden files", but nothing showed up.

I am trying to install Tinker's Construct. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: Mods usually go into the folder `mods` including Tinkers Construct. Jarmods (mods that modify the Minecraft.jar) usually go there too unless they are basemods, those require their own profile because of a change in checksums (the launcher will not start the game then)

Answer (score 1):

Grab a copy of forge at http://files.minecraftforge.net
Then grab Tinkers' Construct from http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1287648-tinkers-construct
Make sure it's for the same version of Minecraft as the version of forge version of Minecraft.

Run the forge installer (you need to have downloaded the vanilla version of Minecraft before you can run the installer)

Run Minecraft using the new profile named Forge. This should create a mods folder in your minecraft directory

Mc directory is in
    %APPDATA%/.Minecraft
on windows and on Mac it's in
    ~/Library/Application Support/Minecraft

Drop the Tinkers' Construct file into your mods folder, start up Minecraft using the forge profile again and then you're done

Answer (score -1):

You are probably in the wrong folder, to access the minecraft folder type %appdata% in the searchbar, open .minecraft, open versions, *game version number*, and the .jar should be there. If it isn't, this might have to do with the fact that you aren't using the newer version of the minecraft launcher (or if you're using the pirated version)